# Can the same Laravel route be part of more than one group?

Tags: laravel, filter, laravel-4, permissions, routes

I'm encountering some rather odd behavior in Laravel 4.2. I have a bunch of permissions-based route groups, e.g.

```
Route::group( [ "before" => "filter_can_access_site"] , function() { ...
Route::group( [ "before" => "filter_can_edit"] , function() { ...
```

There are some situations where I want to put the same route in both groups,  e.g. a "get" request to show data.

I'm finding that this works when I use slightly different syntax to do the same thing, e.g.

```
Route::group( [ "before" => "filter_can_access_site"] , function() {
    Route::get( "scripts/{id}", "ScriptsController@show" ); 
    ...
Route::group( [ "before" => "filter_can_edit"] , function() { ...
    Route::resource( "scripts", "ScriptsController", array("only" => array( "show" )));
```

But if I use the same syntax in both groups, routes in the first group fail the filter.

Is there an explanation for this? Should I avoid putting the same route in multiple groups? I can do that... but then why should this weird syntax workaround even exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest groups like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // Your routes

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'commissions'], function()

        // Get request would go here.

    }); 
});
```